# Cannot set property 'data' of undefined - TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I get the error "Cannot set property 'data' of undefined" when I try to set a value in *options.data*.

**My interface:**

```
interface GanttOptions {
        data: Array<Row>
        ...    
    }
```

**Controller :**

```
class ProfileController{

options: GanttOptions

    constructor() {           
        this.options = {
            data: [],
            ...
        }
     }

    getForOneProfile(datedeb, profile, datefin) {
        this.options.data = this.ganttData;
    };

    class ProfileViewComponent {

        constructor() {
            this.bindings = {             
                options: '=',
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

EDIT :
I found my mistake, it was in the component class. The binding for *options* was '<' instead of '='.

Comment: Where is `this.ganttData` defined and why are you setting a value in a `getter` method? Could it be that `this.options.data` is set to `undefined` or `null` in some other method?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that `options` is also used in another controller